# Parse html string to json using htmlparser2

Tags: javascript, json, html-parsing

I'm trying to use htmlparser2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) to parse a html raw string into json.

But its usage only logs out the tag/text, what I want is the json like its livedemo (http://demos.forbeslindesay.co.uk/htmlparser2/), so that I can filter the elements I want.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried to get returns from paser.write(html), but it returns nothing, and I also tried to return data from *ondataend*, still no luck.

Comment: Showing the code of what you tried is better than describing it and more helpful to anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

took a look of the source codes, it seems there is a helper method **parseDOM** that can do the trick:

```
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
elements = htmlparser.parseDOM(htmlString);
```

so the **elements** will be the array of objects like the livedemo.

hope this will help anyone encounters the same problem.